# python code to upload files to sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint

i want to be able to export `.csv` or `excel workbooks` directly into Sharepoint using python code - is this even possible?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found something that can help you!
You need this library: [Office365 REST python client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/), to connect to the Microsoft API and upload your files ([here](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload_file.py) you can find an example that does exactly what do you want). I think that you can upload both .csv and .xls, you should try and let us know!

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, I will recommend you to use [Office365-Rest-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) to consume SharePoint Rest API.

You can use the following code to upload file:

```
import os

from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_user_credentials, test_team_site_url

ctx = ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_credentials(test_user_credentials)

path = "../../data/report #123.csv"
with open(path, 'rb') as content_file:
    file_content = content_file.read()

list_title = "Documents"
target_folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).root_folder
name = os.path.basename(path)
target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content).execute_query()
print("File has been uploaded to url: {0}".format(target_file.serverRelativeUrl))
```

More information for reference: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload_file.py

Comment: Fixed Link: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload.py